# How can I display the all the table names, along with their count of column names?

Tags: oracle

My database has a lot of tables. How can I display all the table names along with the count of column names in each table?

myoutput:

```
------------
table_name       count(*)
----------       --------
table_t1            12
x_a                  5
Y_k                 23
samptabl             0
```

Comment: Do you mean you want name of tables and number of columns it contains?

Comment: Do you like to count columns include or exclude hidden columns?

Comment: I don't believe that your application contains **a lot** of tables, at least not according Oracle perception. Probably nubmer of Oracle internal tables is already bigger than yours.

Comment: Do you like to count tables and columns include or exclude "MATERIALIZED VIEWs" and "MATERIALIZED VIEW LOGs"? Do you like to count number of column also in Nested Tables?

Answer (score 2):

Use `USER_TAB_COLS` view to get the column_count.

```
SELECT table_name, count(*) column_count
FROM   user_tab_cols
GROUP BY table_name;
```

Comment: Note: Dictionary View USER_TAB_COLS also shows VIEWS and CLUSTER not only TABLES!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the name of the table with the number of columns in it, use DBA's answer here.

If you want name of the table and the number of rows in it, use the following:

```
SELECT table_name, num_rows
  FROM user_tables;
```

The numbers of rows in this query represent the numbers when the table was last analyzed. To return the latest numbers run `ANALYSE tablename` before running this query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know all table_names and columns count in your Entire Database then here is the query.

Query : SELECT TABLE_NAME,COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) as No_Of_Cols 
        FROM ALL_TAB_COLS 
        GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;

Thanks,
Venu.

Comment: Note: Dictionary View USER_TAB_COLS also shows VIEWS and CLUSTER not only TABLES!

Answer (score -1):

SELECT table_name, count(*) column_count
FROM   all_tables
GROUP BY table_name;

Comment: Select from ALL_TABLES does not return any count of columns.

Comment: Please try the query and give a valid comment. I tried it it returns the column count for all the systables.

Comment: My comment is valid, dictionary view ALL_TABLES does not show you any column properties, thus you cannot count number of columns. This query returns always "1" for "column_count" if ALL_TABLES is grouped by TABLE_NAME.

Comment: it returns column count as 1 if u use systables instead of all_tables, works well for me in oracle 10.